# How can I make the form be sent to an email only if all the information has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

---

I've finished making a form for my website and I've set in the action attribute of form an email where I want this form to be sent, but I never receive anything. My other problem is how can I make the form only be allowed to be sent to the email if all the inputs have been filled and if the checkbox has been ticked? Else receives an error saying you have to fill everything. My idea is to make a Q&A, a person submits their info and question and receive an email with an answer, but I'm not receiving anything and I want the form to have a certain specification to be sent. I'll leave below the HTML of the Q&A tab and only the CSS relevant to that tab. I guess this can be fixed with if statements in JS but I tried and haven't had luck.

---

***Code***

```css
/*Everything beneath has to do with the Q&A tab*/

#Q-A-BG {
  background: url('Images/Q&A-BG.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

;
.Questions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Questions h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.Questions input[type='text'],
.Questions input[type=email],
.Questions textarea {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.Questions input,
.Questions textarea {
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.Questions textarea {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
}

.InputSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.InputSection select,
.InputSection option {
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.InputSection label {
  align-self: start;
  margin-left: 550px;
}

.InputSection a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.InputSection a:hover,
.InputSection a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.InputSection button {
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 560px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #5995DA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Checkbox input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#SubmitButton:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#SubmitButton:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.InputSection input[type='text']:invalid,
.InputSection input[type='email']:invalid,
.InputSection input[type='checkbox']:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #D55C5F;
  color: #D55C5F;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.InputSection input[type='text']:valid,
.InputSection input[type='email']:valid {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <title>What's out there</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>

  </style>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../styles.css' />
</head>

<body id='Q-A-BG'>
  <header class="Header Subsection">
    <!-- This is the menu-->
    <nav class="Header-Container">
      <ul class="Menu SubsectionMenu">
        <li><a href="../WOT.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Q&A.html">Q&A</a></li>
        <li><a href="Images.html">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="Sections/Blog.html" class="Links">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <article class="Questions">
    <!--This has to do with the Information section-->
    <h1> Submit your question</h1>
    <form action='WOT.QuestionsAnswers@gmail.com' method='get' class='Information-Section'>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label for='full-name'> First name</label>
        <input id='full-name' name='full-name' type='text' placeholder="First Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label for='full-name'> Last name</label>
        <input id='full-name' name='full-name' type='text' placeholder="Last Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label for='email'> Email</label>
        <input id='email' name='email' type='email' placeholder='Your Email' />
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label for='Education'>Level of education</label>
        <select id='Education' name='Education'>
          <option value='None'></option>
          <option value='Hs'>High School</option>
          <option value='Pu'>Physics undergraduate</option>
          <option value='Pg'>Physics graduate</option>
          <option value='Al'>Adult with little knowledge of physics</option>
          <option value='As'>Adult with some knowledge of physics</option>
          <option value='Ac'>Adult with college level knowledge of physics</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label for='abstract'> Your question</label>
        <textarea id='abstract' name='abstract' placeholder="Be precise and describe your question in less than 100 words"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <label class='Checkbox' for='available'>
                    <input id='available' name='available' type='checkbox' value='Agrees to the terms'/>
                    <span> I accept the <a href="#"> Terms and Conditions</a></span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="InputSection">
        <button id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put ["required"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) in the input type tag

i.e.

```
<input id='full-name' name='full-name' type='text' required placeholder="First Name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `required` in the end of your input field.

E.g.: `<input id='email' name='email' type='email' placeholder='Your Email' required/>`

From [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp):

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out
> before submitting the form.
>
> Note: The required attribute works with the following input types:
> text, search, URL, tel, email, password, date pickers, number,
> checkbox, radio and file.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, I guess I keep on learning stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

there is html attribute which allow you to validate if field contains something called [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) what you have to do is to insert it in every input you want to contain something or not be empty even the check-box like the following

```
<input type="text" name="" required>
```

or you can validate the form with JavaScript if you want to.

And what you have to do about [form submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) is to pass `mailto` before write the email thereafter write it like the following

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:someone@example.com">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Gad, but I want the form to reach an email address, not a website. Wouldn't passing the whole URL send it to a page?

Comment: I added mailto and no luck. I checked out multiple websites and most of them have a weird JavaScript code but I don't understand it. If I copied it I'd need to change some stuff but I don't understand it. You got any idea :/ Do you think I should write another question here in Stack?

Comment: add it like this `mailto:` or in uppercase `MAILTO:`

Comment: and if you want to submit a form for an advance I recommend you to use server side languages

Comment: <form method='POST' action='MAILTO:wot.questionsanswers@gmail.com'>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218854/discussion-between-aaron-serpilin-and-gad).

Comment: had you forget to upvote it or it is unclear I have to make some edits